# presentViewController hides the Navigation Controller (iOS7)

Tags: ios

I want each of my 3 views to have a "Nav" button. When you click on that button it opens up a modal view that has 3 buttons. Each button (ex: View 1, View 2..) would take you to the corresponding view but for some reason after that segue the Navigation Controller (with the status bar, title etc) is hidden.

This is what my action:

**mainNavController.h**

```
- (IBAction)openUpcomingReleases:(id)sender {
    UpcomingReleasesViewController *upcomingReleases = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"upcomingReleases"];
    upcomingReleases.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:upcomingReleases animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using storyboards and not using segues?

Comment: If you're using storyboard, you should learn how to do segues.  If you want the presented view to be contained by the navigation controller, this definitely isn't the code you're looking for.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do.  If you want to hide the back button, then you should probably present the view modally.  And the fact that the nav bar isn't there is a big clue to the end user that they can't just back out of this view, they have to do something else.

Comment: You know what they say about pictures and thousands of words.

Answer (score 3):

Everything here is working as intended.

A navigation controller's navigation bar will only show up for view controllers that are contained by that navigation controller.  Here, you're presenting a modal view.  It's not contained by the navigation controller.

If you want the navigation bar to continue to appear:

- If it's purely a matter of style, put a navigation bar on the modal scene you're presenting in the interface builder.
- If you need to modally present a view that should be contained in a navigation controller, then you need to present a navigation controller--not a view controller.
- Finally, if the view you're presenting is intended to be part of the navigation controller's navigation stack, then you need to present it with a push, not a modal segue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Embed a UINavigation controller to the upcomingReleases View Controller

and give StoryBoard Id for the navigation controller as upcomingReleasesNavi 

then write the code , it will present with Navigation bar.

- (IBAction)openUpcomingReleases:(id)sender {

                UIViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier
:@"upcomingReleasesNavi"];

                svc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
                [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```